# How to call a function of a class from another class?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to know how I can call my `index` function available in the `Appointments` class, structure like this:

```
class Appointments extends CI_Controller 
{
public function __construct() 
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('session');

    if ($this->session->userdata('language'))
    {
        $this->config->set_item('language', $this->session->userdata('language'));
        $this->lang->load('translations', $this->session->userdata('language'));
    }
    else
    {
        $this->lang->load('translations', $this->config->item('language'));
    }
}

/**
 * @param string $appointment_hash 
 */

public function index($appointment_hash = '') 
{...
```

from another class called `Backend_api`. Usually for call a function I load the model but in this case I've no model but only a class. Sorry if the question is stupid, but I'm new in `CodeIgniter` and I've found nothing that could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From same class you can call like this

```
$this->index($appointment_hash);
```

You can extend the appointments class in backend_api and also don't create a function name as index() in backend_api controller

```
class Backend_api extends Appointments {
public function __construct() 
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->index($appointment_hash);

}

}
```

Comment: The problem's now that I've already have an extends, how I can extend multiple class at this point?

Comment: You can't (http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php)
To solve this, you could just create an instance of your Appointments  class within Backend_api as suggested above.
A more elegant way to do that is to use Dependancy Injection: http://php-di.org/doc/understanding-di.html / code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/dependency-injection-in-php--net-28146

Answer (score 0):

That's very easy, just do:

```
$this-> index(<parameter>);
```

I HIGHLY recommend you look at the PHP documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: Nope man, I'm not in the same class I want to call the index function located in the Appointments class from the class Backend_api

Comment: Apologies, from your code example, it looks a lot like you are in the same class, but I didn't your comment properly.
If you're trying to access a function from another, you can always create an instance of your Appointments class in Backend_api...or make you index() function a statis function.